# Efficient Lower Casing in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Right now I use the below code to change an entire column to lower case.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this - I have around 150K rows in my worksheet.

It takes some time to complete and sometimes I get an `Out of Memory` error.

**First Sub**

```
Sub DeletingFl()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws1 = Sheets("Raw Sheet")

ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.[a1], ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
rng1.AutoFilter 1, "Florida"
    If rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
    Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count - 1)
    rng1.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
ws1.AutoFilterMode = False    
Call DeletingEC
End Sub

Sub DeletingEC()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet    
Dim rng1 As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws1 = Sheets("Raw Sheet")

ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.[a1], ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
rng1.AutoFilter 1, "East Coast"
If rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
    Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count - 1)
    rng1.EntireRow.Delete
End If
ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
Worksheets("Raw Sheet").Activate    
Call Concatenating
End Sub
```

**Second Sub**

```
Sub Concatenating()

Columns(1).EntireColumn.Insert
Columns(2).EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

Dim lngLastRow As Long
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("A2:A" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=F2 & ""_"" & G2"
Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Title"       
Call LowerCasing
End Sub

Sub Lowercasing()
Dim myArr, LR As Long, i As Long
       LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
myArr = Range("A1:A" & LR)
       For i = 1 To UBound(myArr)
              myArr(i, 1) = LCase(myArr(i, 1))
       Next i
Range("A1:A" & LR).Value = myArr
Set ExcelSheet = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this just now using 65530 rows (using very simple, since character values), and it ran perfectly fine in less than a second. What kind of data do you have in your sheet?

Comment: Also, what version of Excel are you using? I tested in 2003.

Comment: The data contains only text. Sometimes, it works OK and other times I get an 'Out of Memory' error. Also, does `Set ExcelSheet = Nothing` help solve this problem of 'Out of Memory'. Using Excel 2007

Comment: Well, you never appear to `Set ExcelSheet` to anything in the first place, so I doubt that would help. ;-)  You may want to use `Option Explicit` in to help make sure your variables are covered; this would flag your `Set ExcelSheet = Nothing`. I just tested again in 2010 with no issues. However, since you say the problem is intermittent, I'm thinking you have something else going on that may even be unrelated to this code specifically. How big is your Excel file? Do you have any other code within the project? Does it make a difference if this is the only file opened at any given time?

Comment: that line will do nothing, as ExcelSheet is not defined until you set it to nothing

Comment: 1) Size is ~32mb 2) Yes, I have other code before this which does some copy-paste (without using clipboard memory) and filtering-deleting - since, this was the error area I only reference this here. You are right, this might not be the problem area. I think it has to do something with memory allocation (not sure, just a guess) 3) It doesn't. I have only this file opened.

Comment: Would you mind then adding any other code to your original question that runs *before* this `Sub`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there's a bit of redundancy and definitely an issue with the array.

I think you can remove the Lowercasing() function and enhance Concatenating to do the lowercasing for you:

```
Sub Concatenating()
    Dim lRowCount As Long
    Dim lngLastRow As Long

    'Do this first while values in column A
    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Columns(1).EntireColumn.Insert

    'Meh... :P
    'We're looping through code in the Lower Casing so no need to copy this and then loop through
    'Columns(2).EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)



    For lRowCount = 1 To lngLastRow
        'I read a long time ago that LCase$ is faster than LCase; may not be noticable on today's machines
        'It wont' hurt to use LCase$
         Range("A" & lRowCount) = LCase$(Range("B" & lRowCount))
    Next lRowCount

        'Not sure what this does but may need to adjust accoringly
        Range("A2:A" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=F2 & ""_"" & G2"
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Title"

    'No need...already lower cased
    'Call Lowercasing
End Sub
```

Comment: One note. you could replace `Range("A1").Select ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Title"` With: `Range("A1).Value = "Title"`

Answer (score 6):

Use the spreadsheet to do it. I put some data in `$A$1:$A$384188`, and made an array formula in `$B$1:$B$384188`: `{=UPPER($A$1:$A$384188)}`. It's immediate and doesn't use much memory.

Looping through VBA will always be much much slower and more memory intensive.
You can use VBA to create the formula and copy paste back the data by value.

Comment: Actually array formulas can be expensive memory wise.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the error sometimes because of how much stuff you are trying to pack into an array.  Everything that you put in that array must fit inside your available memory.

Something like this should work better (note this is untested code):

```
Sub Lowercasing()
Const MaxArraySize As Integer = 1000
Dim myArr, Rng As Range, LR As Long, i As Long, j As Long, ArrayLen As Integer
       LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       For i = 1 To LR Step MaxArraySize
           If LR - i < MaxArraySize Then
               ArrayLen = LR - i + 1
           Else
               ArrayLen = MaxArraySize
           End If
           Set Rng = Range("A" & i & ":A" & i + ArrayLen - 1)
           myArr = Rng
           For j = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
               myArr(j, 1) = LCase(myArr(j, 1))
           Next j
           Rng.Value = myArr
       Next i
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The general idea is to make the update in a series of smaller updates.  You can play with the MaxArraySize constant to find a good balance between speed and memory usage.

You'll also want to add an error handler to ensure that the ScreenUpdating gets turned back on in case of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method to lowercasing each cell in a column, maybe it's worth a shot:

```
Public Sub toLowerCase()
    Dim lr As Integer
    For lr = 1 To Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
       Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(lr, 1) = LCase(Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(lr, 1).Value)
    Next lr
End Sub
```

Rather than creating an array and resetting the range, this simply uses the UsedRange and sets the value as it goes. This avoids the need for arrays, which could be problematic when messing with data of this size.

FYI ... I noticed in your code snippet you do copying. If you're doing copying on a large amount of cells, it's **much** faster to set each cell value (e.g. `cellTarget.Value = cellSource.Value`) than it is to copy one cell value to another.

Also, I notice you set **ScreenUpdating** to False ... where do you set it back to True? In addition to toggling ScreenUpdating during these large calculations, you may want to think about [setting **Calculation** to manual](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm). Sometimes when worksheets get this much activity Excel will calculate too often. By setting this to manul, you avoid over the overhead.

Here's an example using the same snippet of code above, but this time with ScreenUpdating and Calculation settings provided:

```
Public Sub toLowerCase()
    Dim lr As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For lr = 1 To Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
       Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(lr, 1) = LCase(Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(lr, 1).Value)
    Next lr
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Generally, assigning into an array is much faster than working with cells directly. I would disagree with your first point here, though I think you are right about the size of the array possibly causing it's own headaches.

Comment: Agree with Gaffi. Avoid cell by cell loops, especially for large ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without loops and without working columns

1. Dump the range (single row or column) into a 1D string array
2. Take the lower case of the string and dump it back over the range

*code*

```
Sub NoLoops()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim strOut As String
Dim strDelim As String

strDelim = ","
Set rng1 = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
X = LCase$(Join(Application.Transpose(rng1), strDelim))
rng1 = Application.Transpose(Split(X, strDelim))
End Sub
```

*shorter version*

```
Sub OneLine()
Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) = Application.Transpose(Split(LCase$(Join(Application.Transpose(Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))), ",")), ","))
End Sub
```

**`[Update for the 65536 cell limit with Transpose]`**

For 150k rows this method does need to *chunk* the column into 2^16 parts given the limits on `Application Transpose`. Which is an annoying adjustment to "no loops" becoming "minimal loops"

```
Sub Transpose_Adjust()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim lngLim As Long
Dim lngCalac As Long
Dim strOut As String
Dim strDelim As String

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
lngCalc = .Calculation
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

strDelim = ","
Set rng1 = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
'TRANSPOSE limited to 65536 cells
lngLim = Application.Min(16, Int(rng1.Cells.Count / 2 ^ 16))
For lngCnt = 1 To lngLim
Set rng2 = rng1.Cells(1).Offset((lngCnt - 1) * 2 ^ 16, 0).Resize(2 ^ 16, 1)
X = LCase$(Join(Application.TransPose(rng2), strDelim))
rng2.Value2 = Application.TransPose(Split(X, strDelim))
Next lngCnt

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
Calculation = lngCalc
End With

End Sub
```